# Error! Could not verify Stripe's SSL certificate.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am trying to use Stripe with my Ruby app and keep getting this error:

```
Error! Could not verify Stripe's SSL certificate. Please make sure that your network is not intercepting certificates. (Try going to https://api.stripe.com/v1 in your browser.) If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com. (Network error: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed).
```

Why am I getting this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Stripe's Ruby bindings verify the HTTPS certificate on Stripe's servers (`api.stripe.com`) to ensure you're really communicating with Stripe and not with a malicious third-party (a.k.a. a "[man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)").

There are a number of reasons that can cause this error. First, you should make sure you're using the latest versions of the following:

- the [stripe-ruby](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby) gem
- the [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem
- Ruby
- OpenSSL

If you're working in a corporate environment, it's possible your firewall replaces HTTPS certificates in order to be able to decrypt HTTPS traffic. (This is essentially the same thing as a man-in-the-middle attack.)

If you're still having this issue, you can disable the SSL verification by including this line:

```
Stripe.verify_ssl_certs = false
```

However, I would **strongly** advise against doing this. It *might* be okay in a development environment, but you should **never** do this in a production environment.

EDIT: We're currently investigating [this issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/issues/382) -- it seems it might have been introduced in a recent version of the stripe-ruby gem. For now, it seems downgrading to version 1.34.0 will fix the "Could not verify Stripe's SSL certificate" issue.

Comment: I'm using PHP and was able to temporarily use this in my development environment: `\Stripe\Stripe::setVerifySslCerts(false);`

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal. 
Run command $curl -v https://api.stripe.com

For intermittent issue like I had you may have to run this command 10 to 20 times back to back. Then stop and start again until you see the error.

The IP address it attempts to connect to should match an IP address of the domain you are trying to access. For stripe you can check valid ip addresses here https://stripe.com/docs/ips

If the IP address does not match or if the IP address is the same as your network then you could be experiencing man in the middle attack.

In my case I was experiencing this issue with aws and stripe because they use curl to connect. Returning error 60 no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name.

A workaround is to edit /etc/hosts file. 
Hard code an IP address of the endpoint

XXX.XXX.X.X    api.stripe.com

This will stop the issue, but should be revisited because your application will fail in the future if the IP address for the endpoint is changed or removed.